# How to get next Friday 13th since the given LocalDate

Tags: java, dayofweek, localdate, dayofmonth

I need to get next **Friday 13th** since the given date using `LocalDate`.

How it could be implemented?

Comment: Yet another approach would use [`YearMonth#atDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#atDay(int)).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using **only** methods [`plusMonths()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths(long)), [`withDayOfMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#withDayOfMonth(int)) of the `LocalDate` class.

The starting point is to adjust the ***day of the month*** of the *given date* to the target day `13`. If the day of month of the *given date* is greater than `13`, then the current date will be assigned to the ***13th*** day of the next month, otherwise to the ***13th*** day of the current month.

And then check in the loop whether the ***day of the week*** of the current date is *Friday*. Note that *days of the week* in **java.util.time** API are represented by *enum* `DayOfWeek`.

This approach allows to find the target date only withing a **couple of iterations** by *skipping the whole month*.

To avoid hard-coded values and make the code reusable, the *day of the month* and the *day of the week* are expected as parameters of the method `getNextDay()`.

```
public static LocalDate getNextDay(LocalDate date, int dayOfMonth, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    LocalDate current = date.getDayOfMonth() > dayOfMonth ?
            date.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth) :
            date.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth);

    while (current.getDayOfWeek() != dayOfWeek) {
        current = current.plusMonths(1);
    }
    return current;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getNextDay(LocalDate.now(), 13, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
    System.out.println(getNextDay(LocalDate.now().plusMonths(5), 13, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
}
```

**Output**

```
2022-05-13  -  from now ('2022-03-16')
2023-01-13  -  from '2022-08-16'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by just adding **7 days** to your `LocalDate` and you will get the expected day:

**For example:**

```
 LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

 //tomorrow
 LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1);

 // next week day
 LocalDate nextWeekDay= today.plusDays(7);
```

**Or get it by this one :**

```
today.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
```

Answer (score 0):

First we look for the next Friday from the given date (getNextFriday). Then we check if she is 13 (is13Friday.)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean is13Friday = false;
    LocalDate nextFriday = LocalDate.now();
    while (!is13Friday) {
        nextFriday = getNextFriday(nextFriday);
        is13Friday = is13Friday(nextFriday);
    }
    System.out.println(nextFriday);

}

public static LocalDate getNextFriday(LocalDate d) {
    return d.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
}

public static boolean is13Friday(LocalDate d) {
    return d.getDayOfMonth() == 13;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IntStream` to iterate through days:

```
public static LocalDate findFridayThirteen(LocalDate fromDate) {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            .mapToObj(fromDate::plusDays)
            .filter(date -> date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY 
                    && date.getDayOfMonth() == 13)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();
}
```

Or, you can iterate only Fridays:

```
public static LocalDate findFridayThirteen(LocalDate fromDate) {
    LocalDate nextFriday = fromDate.with(
            TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 7)
            .mapToObj(nextFriday::plusDays)
            .filter(date -> date.getDayOfMonth() == 13)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();
}
```

Or, you can iterate only the 13 of each month:

```
public static LocalDate findFridayThirteen(LocalDate fromDate) {
    LocalDate nextThirteen = fromDate.getDayOfMonth() > 13 
            ? fromDate.withDayOfMonth(13).plusMonths(1) 
            : fromDate.withDayOfMonth(13);
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            .mapToObj(nextThirteen::plusMonths)
            .filter(date -> date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();
}
```

Test:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1);

LocalDate friday13 = findFridayThirteen(date);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);

System.out.println(friday13.format(formatter));
```

Output:

```
Friday, May 13, 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LocalDateTime nextFriday13() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    while (now.getDayOfMonth() != 13) {
        now = now.plusDays(1);
    }
    
    while (!now.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)) {
        now = now.plusMonths(1);
    }
    
    return now;
}
```